# What does the term Synchronization primitive mean in python threading?

Tags: python, python-multithreading

The term Synchronization primitive is used in many places in the documentation of threading. I have referenced one such usage in the description of [RLock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#rlock-objects):

> A reentrant lock is a synchronization primitive that may be acquired multiple times by the same thread. Internally, it uses the concepts of “owning thread” and “recursion level” in addition to the locked/unlocked state used by primitive locks. In the locked state, some thread owns the lock; in the unlocked state, no thread owns it.

What does synchronization primitive mean?

Comment: _"This module [`threading`] constructs higher-level threading interfaces on top of the lower level `_thread` module."_ I think _primitive_ means from `_thread` module. From the `_thread` module: _"This module provides low-level primitives for working with multiple threads"_

Comment: It means some operation from which one can build mechanisms to synchronize multithreaded code. The word "primitive" hints at the operation cannot be broken down into simpler building blocks (from the point of view of your code).

Answer (score 0):

It is not a Python threading specific term, but more broadly used in the context of concurrency.

A *primative* refers to a basic or fundamental mechanism from which more complex mechanisms may be synthesised.  A thread *synchronisation* primitive is a mechanism that allows one thread (or in some cases multiple threads) to wait until some other thread has reached some point in its execution.

An `RLock` (*reentrant lock*) is an example of a *mutex* (mutual exclusion) semaphore.  A mutex is used to protect a resource (for example a memory region or hardware device) from concurrent access from two threads.

So for example if thread A acquires access to a resource with `threading.RLock.acquire` then while it holds that resource, thread B attempts to acquire the same resource, it will also call `threading.RLock.acquire`, but the resource is already locked, so thread B will *block* pending `threading.RLock.release` call from thread A.  When thread A releases the resource, thread B may then continue (i.e. `threading.RLock.acquire` in thread B returns with the resource locked and *owned* now by thread B.

The *reentrant* part refers to the fact that the owning thread may call `threading.RLock.acquire` for the same resource multiple times (which may occur in nested calls in the same device driver for example).  That is to say it cannot block on its own lock. Which can happen if you use a regular binary-semaphore for mutual exclusion.  When `acquire` is called, a counter is incremented, and on `release` the counter is decremented - the mutex is not *unlocked* on `release` unless the counter becomes zero.

Generally (i.e. not Python `threading` specific), synchronisation primitives include:

- counting semaphores
- binary semaphores
- mutex semaphores (or locks)
- signals
- event flags
- condition variables

Caution is necessary with mutexes to avoid deadlock, where for example thread A waits on a resource held by thread B while holding a resource that thread B is trying to acquire.  One way to avoid such instances is to have a single thread access the shared resource and have other threads make requests of this "server" thread.  In that way no mutual exclusion is required - requests are serialised by the owner thread.  Such a pattern relies on another *primitive* - IPC (inter-process communication) primitives, such as message queues or mailboxes.